# how to write a postgresql support function

Tags: c, postgresql

I am trying to write a support function in postgresql to set the selectivity.

I have a function

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(pgq3c_sindist_5);
Datum pgq3c_sindist_5(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
```

I wish to have a support function to set the selectivity.
The function pgq3c_sindist_5 return boolean, and I have a
support function

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(pgq3c_join_selectivity);
Datum pgq3c_join_selectivity(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
  Node    *rawreq = (Node *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
  Node    *unknown = (Node *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(1);
  Node    *ret = NULL;
  Datum radDatum;
  double rad;
 if (IsA(rawreq, SupportRequestSelectivity))
    {
      SupportRequestSelectivity *req = (SupportRequestSelectivity *) rawreq;

      radDatum = llast_node(Datum,req->args);
      rad = DatumGetFloat8(radDatum);


      elog(WARNING,"rad = %lf",rad);

      /* I would like to make the selectivity a function of rad */
      req->selectivity = 0.05;
      ret = (Node *) req;
    }
```

My non support function has five arguments. I wish my support function
to use the fifth argument pf pgq3c_sindist_5 to be used in my support
function. My code doesn't dump code, but my rad always ends up as 0.0,
when I'm 100 percent sure that I'm not passing in a zero as any of my arguments
to my primary function.

If I'm reading the source correctly, the SupportRequestSelectivity has arguments
of

```
/* Input fields: */
struct PlannerInfo *root;   /* Planner's infrastructure */
Oid         funcid;         /* function we are inquiring about */
List       *args;           /* pre-simplified arguments to function */
Oid         inputcollid;    /* function's input collation */
bool        is_join;        /* is this a join or restriction case? */
int         varRelid;       /* if restriction, RTI of target relation */
JoinType    jointype;       /* if join, outer join type */
struct SpecialJoinInfo *sjinfo; /* if outer join, info about join */
```

From this I think that the List *args is supposed to be the arguments of my main function,
and I should be able to parse this.

Am I totally barking up the wrong tree?

I'd like to find the value of the arguments of my main function in my support function.

EDIT: my new code looks like

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(pgq3c_join_selectivity);
Datum pgq3c_join_selectivity(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
  Node    *rawreq = (Node *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
  Node    *ret = NULL;
  Datum radDatum;
  double rad;
  double ratio;
  Node *dummy = NULL;
  
  if (IsA(rawreq, SupportRequestSelectivity))
    {
      SupportRequestSelectivity *req = (SupportRequestSelectivity *) rawreq;
      Selectivity s1;
      
      dummy = (Node *) lfirst(list_nth_cell(req->args, 4));

      if (IsA(dummy,Const))
    {
      Const *con = (Const *) dummy;
      radDatum = PointerGetDatum(con->constvalue);
      rad = DatumGetFloat8(radDatum);     
      ratio = 3.14 * rad * rad / 41252.;  /* pi*r^2/whole_sky_area */
      /* clamp at 0, 1*/
      CLAMP_PROBABILITY(ratio);
      //elog(WARNING, "HERE0.... %e", ratio);
      req->selectivity = ratio;
      ret = (Node *) req;
    }
    }
  if (IsA(rawreq, SupportRequestSimplify))
    {
      SupportRequestSimplify *req = (SupportRequestSimplify *) rawreq;      
      PG_RETURN_POINTER((Node *)0);
    }
  if (IsA(rawreq, SupportRequestCost))
    {
      elog(WARNING,"found SupportRequestCost");
      /* Provide some generic estimate */
      SupportRequestCost *req = (SupportRequestCost *) rawreq;

      /* not yet implemented */
      
      ret = (Node *) req;
    }
  PG_RETURN_POINTER(ret);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support function has only one argument, so you should remove the line that calls `PG_GETARG_POINTER(1)`.

To get the fifth element from `req->args`, use

```c
lfirst(list_nth_cell(req->args, 4))
```

Note that the result won't be a `Datum`, but a `Node *`. After all, it need not be a `Const *`, but it might as well be a `Var *` or some other expression.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. I think I have it. I included my code above.